# Should I show the association class in my class diagram?

Tags: database, documentation, uml, class-diagram

For example I have a relationship like this:
**user (0..*)** *buys* **product (0..*)**

Which results in an association class, called **sale**, which has the userID and productID. Just for the question's sake, imagine this **sale** class has NO other attributes, except for these IDs.

My question is, should I show this **sale** class in my class diagram? Or can I just leave it and only show the relationship.

Although I have never seen this done before, I am asking because someone told me you don't need to show the association class if it has no relationship attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the UML 2.5 specifications:

> **11.5.3.2:** An AssociationClass is a declaration of an Association that has a set of Features of its own.

This means that **a many-to-many association with no features of its own is not an association class**. Hence it should not be represented as an association class on the diagram.

The fact that in a database it would be implemented as a "relation" (in the RDBMS sense, i.e. a table) does not change the way the model should be represented: This is an implementation detail.

You could event have an [N-ary association](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#arity) (associating more than 2 classes). It would be represented with a diamond as N-ary connector, but if it has no set of features of its own, it would still not be considered as an association class.

Conversely, if there is a set of feature of its own, then it is an an association class, and then this should be represented on the diagram:

> **11.5.4.** An AssociationClass is shown as a Class symbol attached to the Association path by a dashed line.

Comment: Thank you for a very good answer. But I have one doubt. By features does it also include relationships? Imagine that I need to create a relationship with that sale class. I think then I will need to show that class. Am I right?

Comment: Excellent question ! I was expecting it; this is why I added the paragraph about N-ary associations.  Your comment refers to a ternary association, i.e. an association between three classes.  But if it still has no feature of its own, it's still no association class.  You'll nevertheless have a diamond to connect more than 2 items.

Comment: So do you mean that if I have a many-to many relation between two classes and then if I need to create an association with the resulting class then it means that I should have a ternary relationship? For example: user buys product, results in the sale class. Now if I need to create a relation between the sale class and a provider class for example then does it mean I should have a ternary relation originally? Like this user buys product that belongs to a provider which results in the sale class.

Comment: If we take the UML standard by the letter, yes it should be like this.  However, ternary associations are rarely used in practice.  In addition, the standard says that a property could be represented by an association and conversely, leaving you the choice on how to represent it.  Otherwise stated, you may just show a ternary association, or you may consider the additional association as a property and use an association class.  So here, you have the choice.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the purpose of your UML diagram:

Are you modelling, illustrating, or analysing the **problem domain**? Then don't invent extra concepts. Only show the relevant relationships. Using an n:m relationship as you suggested is probably clearest.

Are you creating a **concrete design**, or are you **documenting** existing code? Introducing a `Sale` concept is an important design decision that should be included in the diagram. Simple classes with no extra properties aren't a problem – simple classes are clean. Showing a direct relationship when you've implemented that relationship with a class could be misleading, but that depends on the context.

For the special case of a **relational database** design, I would usually not show the association class in most cases. It is clear from the n:m relationship that this relationship will be implemented with a separate table, assuming a sufficiently normalized database. But if you want to document the relationships of existing tables, showing a class per table including a class for the Sale would be the clearest approach.